# What is a static ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Consider the ArrayList below:

```
static ArrayList<String> credit_num = new ArrayList<String>();
```

What does it mean to have static before the ArrayList?

Comment: I guess we can guess that you're talking about Java, but it may make a difference. Surely you can google "Java static"?

Comment: What is a `static` anything in Java?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword `static` before a variable in Java means that it is shared by all instances of that particular Class.